# Pygame and Python Clickable Objects

Tags: python, pygame

I have been coding a simple game. I am trying to make one of my sprites clickable, and execute `loaddeath()` when clicked.

I have been running into several errors though.

```
screen.blit(chinese, (randomx1, randomy1))
screen.blit(green, (randomx2, randomy2))
screen.blit(eden, (randomx3, randomy3))

screen.blit(obama, (randomx5, randomy5))
screen.blit(blue, (randomx6, randomy6))

#I want this object to be clickable
screen.blit(kevin, (randomx8, randomy8))
screen.blit(hud, (0, 0))
```

My event Loop:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
```

What do I need to add?

Answer (score 1):

To detect the mouse click you need to use `pygame.mouse.get_pressed()`

and you also need to make a rect for the object you want to make clickable.

Then, write an if statement using `collidepoint()`. This will tell you if a point is in a rect.

So, do this:

```
if pygame.mouse.get_pressed()[0] and sprite_rect.collidepoint(mouse_pos):
    #do action
```

This is basically saying if the mouse button is clicked and the mouse and rect are touching do something, where `sprite_rect` is the rect you made for the object you want clickable and `mouse_pos` is the mouse's current position.

(to get the mouse's position use `pygame.mouse.get_pos()` in your loop)

For more info on all these methods look [here.](http://www.pygame.org/docs/)